# How to Hide an Element using Jquery and Coffeescript in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I would like to hide an element in a page on my Rails site, but I'm not yet that familiar with Jquery or Coffeescript.

This code works in the console:

```
$('#TheButton').click(function(){$('#TheText').toggle()});
```

I then [converted](http://js2coffee.org/) it to Coffescript:

```
$("#TheButton").click ->
  $("#TheText").toggle()
```

But it doesn't work on my Rails page. How do I fix it? Below is the generated javascript file:

```
(function() {
jQuery(function() { 
# stuff... 
  });

  $('form').on('click', '.add_fields', function(event) {
  # stuff... 
  });

  $("#TheButton").click(function() {
    return $("#TheText").toggle();
  });

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your JS files are embedded at the top of your layout, every file you have must be wrapped in that jQuery call

Comment: OK, thanks, I had to add in `Jquery ->` before `$("#TheButton")` code.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's selectors don't work until after the page is loaded. You'll need to make sure your code runs *after* the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready ->

  $("#TheButton").click ->
    $("#TheText").toggle()

  # other stuff you want to happen after document load
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
$ ->
```

Before your code to ensure it runs after the DOM is loaded.